# Prove that $n!>n^{n/2}$.

Tags: inequality

Prove that $n!>n^{n/2} \space  \forall $ natural numbers $n>2$. I have tried this problem several times but couldn't get it. Maybe, it's quite trivial but I'm missing something in my ideas. Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you use Stirling approximation ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici What is that?

Comment: So, just forget it ! You will learn that later. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You can still provide an answer using that...I may understand it some day!!

Comment: Not now. Later (probably very soon), you will learn and use it. When you will hear about it, feel free to contact me and we shall discuss about it and its applications.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for that!

Answer (score 9):

Use a multiplicative variant of [Gauss's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss#Anecdotes):
$$
(n!)^2 = (1 \cdot n) (2 \cdot (n-1)) (3 \cdot (n-2)) \cdots
                ((n-2) \cdot 3) ((n-1) \cdot 2) (n \cdot 1)
                \ge n^n
$$

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Using AM, GM inequality,

$$\dfrac{r+n-r}2\ge\sqrt{r(n-r)}$$

Set $r=1,\cdots,n-1$ and multiply

Answer (score 1):

Taking $\log$ on both sides of the inequality yields the equivalent inequality $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n\ln(k)>\frac{n}{2}\ln(2)$.

The latter can be tackled using some integrals. Since $\ln$ is increasing over each interval $[k,k+1]$, the following holds : $\ln(k)\geq \int_k^{k+1}\ln(t)$dt.

Summing for $k=0,\ldots,n$ yields $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n\ln(k) \geq \int_0^{n}\ln(t)dt = n\ln(n) -n$.

It is then trivial to check that for $n\geq 8$, $n\ln(n) -n>\frac{n}{2}\ln(2)$.

It remains to check the inequality for $2\leq n \leq 7$.